# Permission denied in Python

Tags: python, errno

After installing Python on my Mac I probertly made an error.
Pressing the Build command it said

```
[Errno 13] Permission denied
[cmd: ['/usr/local/bin/python3.5', '-u', '/Users/peter/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Packages/User/test-module.py']]
[dir: /Users/peter/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Packages/User]
[path: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Users/peter/.nexustools]
```

How do I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You have not access to run python script in the account or the terminal. You can use to "sudo" or create virtualenv https://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: Thanks for your answer Nikita!!! I use Sublime txt. Regarding sudo - I need to make a modification in a library os so?

Comment: use sudo from where you run your py script.